# Signing in goggles account error

Tags: google-play-store

I have been asked to sign in to goggles account but when I do it gives me error. What might be the cause

Comment: It is possible you are using your goggles.com account credentials to reach google.com. Ascertain you are supplying the right credentials and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Check caps lock. Check the username is the same as one you have used before. Then carefully check the password.

Typing accuracy is crucial. For example, note that you type 'goggles' above when I think you meant 'google'.